# can't change nginx default port

Tags: nginx

I installed nginx on mac os sierra by

```
brew install nginx
```

here one concern brew started nginx service automatically but it shouldn't act like this (I should tell I need a background service or not!!!) but so far so good and localhost:8080 shows default nginx page.
then I tried to change the port in nginx.conf

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}
    include servers/*;
}
```

I restart service but now it's not serving 8080 neither 80

I tried to stop the service and start it my self by

```
sudo nginex
```

I get

```
nginx: [emerg] open() "/usr/local/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

I searched a lot and read a lot about this but I couldn't find similar issue

Comment: Check if it is being run by brew or not `brew services list | grep nginx`. If it is then stop it using `brew services stop nginx`. Then use `sudo nginx`, Port `80` on mac cannot be bound without sudo rights

Comment: There is no nginex and as you can see already used sudo nginex to run

Comment: 'sudo brew services stop nginx' worked for me

Answer (score 0):

It seems your nginx is not running.

Check if nginx is running

```
$ ps -ef | grep nginx
```

When you see something like this

```
    0 10653     1   0  3:32PM ??         0:00.01 nginx: master process nginx
   -2 11498 10653   0  3:37PM ??         0:00.01 nginx: worker process
```

nginx is on. Otherwise it is not.

If nginx is not on run nginx first.

```
$ sudo nginx
```

If you editted nginx file config after nginx is on, you should reload nginx.

```
// assumes nginx is on
$ sudo nginx -s reload
```

By now you should see changes in effect.